# one textbox value in another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value of one textbox and put the same in another textbox.
my code is :

```
<input type="text" value="Keyword" id="one" />
<input type="text" value="Search" id="two" />

<a href="#" id="btn">button</a>
```

jquery:

```
var input = $("#one");

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        alert('dgdhjdgj');
        var oneValue = $('#one').val();
        alert("one value "+ oneValue);
        var twoVal =  $('#two').val($(input).attr('value'));
         alert('two Val' + twoVal);
     });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vtqHV/7/) is here.

Issue : when I change the value of textbox #one, it does not change the value of #two.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what is issue with this?

Comment: when I change the value of textbox #one, it does not change the value of #two.

Comment: so you want to change to change the text of input two as soon as input one text changes, use .change event of input one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Keyword" id="one" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="two" />

<a href="#" id="btn">button</a>
```

**Script**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   var oneValue = $('#one').val();
   $('#two').val(oneValue)

})
```

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/updrP/1/)

Answer (score 2):

`$(input).attr('value')` gets the value of the *value attribute*, which is the *initial* value, not the *current* value.

You had it right two lines earlier. Use `val()`.

Answer (score 1):

write textarea and check it. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/79YJh/)

```
$("#add").click(function(){
 var thenVal = $("#textarea_first").val();
 $("#textarea_second").val(thenVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if all that you want to change the text of second textbox, as soon as you change the text of first textbox, just use jQuery's `change` event.

just try this then:

```
$('#one').on("change",function(){
   $('#two').val($(this).val());
});
```